# Google Sheets Query where Date is Greater than Another Date + 15 Days

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Query formula in Google Sheets where I'm trying to set a condition that shows rows where Col1 > (Col2 +15 days).  I'm not sure how to do the math on the +15 days in the Query formula.

I tried the following code:

```
=Query(A:B,"Select * where Col1>Col2+15")
```

I want it to show me where Column 1 is greater than the Col2 date + 15 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use Datediff within your query:

```
=Query(A:B,"Select * where A is not null and datediff(A,B)>15")
```

[See](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/datediff-function-in-google-sheets-query/)

Comment: Thanks.  To compare it to today, would it be?  `=Query(A:B,"Select * where A is not null and datediff(A,'"&TODAY()&'")>15")`  <-- I'm not getting that to work

Comment: It would be =Query(A:B,"Select * where A is not null and datediff(now(),A)>15") if you want to see if A is more than 15 days before today's date or =Query(A:B,"Select * where A is not null and datediff(A,now())>15") if you want to see if A comes more than 15 days after today's date because the end date comes first in datediff for some reason. TBH I don't know why today() doesn't work the same way, but it appears that datediff truncates any time part of the date that you would get from now() so you get the same result as you would if you could use today().

Answer (score 0):

I would add into the query {A:B,B:B+15}. This will add a third column into your selection with Col2+15 days. Then from there, you can select the first two columns, but still ask whether Col1 is greater than Col3.
=arrayformula(query({A:B,B:B+15},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 > Col3"))

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(QUERY(VALUE(A1:B), 
 "select * where Col1 > Col2+15", 0)))
```

[image]